# A city’s road system consists of streets (which run east-west) and avenues (which run north-south)....

Tags: probability

A city’s road system consists of streets (which run east-west) and avenues (which runnorth-south), and both streets and avenues are numbered sequentially from 1-st to 100-th.  At 1 am, Ivanleaves a pub located at the intersection of 50-th street and 55-th avenue.  His home is at the intersection of55-th street and 58-th avenue.  At each crossroads, Ivan randomly chooses one of four directions to go.  Italways takes him exacly 5 minutes to get from one crossroads to the next.  What is the probability that hewill be at home at 1 : 40 am?Hint: it may be convenient to represent the walk as sampling with replacementfrom the set{N, W, S, E}(north, west, south, east), where the letter indicates which way to go at a givencrossroads

So in my drawing it ends up looking like a 5 rows * 3 column grid with the start at the bottom left and goal at the top right...

it will take 8 intersection crossings to reach the goal, which coincidentally is the summation of the number of rows and columns between the start and goal

I'm thinking the denominator is 4^8, just all the different routes of choosing 8 intersection crossings from the set {N, E, S, W}

NOW the numerator I think would be about going in the direction North 5 times and easts 3 times...

so all the different orderings of 5 norths and 3 easts...

currently I'm having difficulty with this last part (assuming the thinking of my first part is correct)

Comment: Do you mean at or until 1:40 am?

Comment: he arrives at 1:40 am which means he has 8 crossings to get there (40 minutes / 5 minutes)

Comment: @MichaelHoppe It doesn't matter; he can't get there faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thinking is absolutely correct (assuming he's drunk enough to turn back where he came from when reaching an intersection), and you're very close.

The number of orderings of 5 norths and 3 easts is $\binom 83=56$ because you have a sequence of 8 directions, and you're after the number of different ways to choose three of the eight places for the three easts (then fill in the rest with norths).